# how to Create publish mechanism for windows service in c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows application (by c#). I want to create publish mechanism that publish my app on a server like asp.web application publish.
can i do this pattern or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [ClickOnce Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

You publish your application on a server, and clients automatically download new versions as they're available.